# Not getting OTP from firebase (android) (Testing phone number is working)

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am new at android development. I am not getting OTP from firebase in my android project but I can log in using testing the phone numbers. Please look into the issue I am sharing the code shown below. Please help. I have tried this for many different mobile numbers and I also tried for the numbers that are not included in the testing phone numbers. I have also deployed it on the play store but still did not work. Thank You.

```
mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                mVerificationInProgress = false;
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
            }


            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                mVerificationInProgress = false;              
               if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId,
                                   @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                mVerificationId = verificationId;
                mResendToken = token;
                Log.d("OnCodeSent",token+"");
            }
        };
```

here I can print the token which looks good.

```
private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        mVerificationInProgress = true;
    }

    private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
       signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    private void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                                        PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks,         // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                token);             // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
    }
    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),InitialACtivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            errorOtp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateUI(){

    }

    private boolean validatePhoneNumber() {
        return true;
    }

    public void clickSendCode(String number){

        startPhoneNumberVerification(number);

    }

    public void clickVerifyCode(View v){

        if(mVerificationId == null){
            return;
        }

        verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId, otpEntered);

    }
```

Comment: i noticed it doesn't send OTP is the number you are registering is in the device

Comment: Thanks for the response, Please explain why? How can I get rid of it.